# Не работает анимация в ListView, отображаемому в фрагменте android

Tags: android, listview, анимация, android-fragment, adapter

Пытаюсь реализовать серверный запрос, после чего удалить элемент ListView, по которому кликнул пользователь. Во время запроса к серверу в View строки добавляется ProgressBar, анимация которого не работает (ProgressBar становится видимым, но не вращается). ListView находится в Fragment, который появляется при некоторых действиях пользователя.

Исходный код инициализации View ListAdapter'a:

```
private void createNewView(final UserInfo userInfo, final int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listadapter_row_item, null, false);

    TextView mainText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dutyUsersListadapterMainTextview);
    mainText.setText(userInfo.lastname);

    TextView additionalText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dutyUsersListadapterAdditionalTextview);
    additionalText.setText(String.format("%s %s", userInfo.firstname, userInfo.middlename));

    mViews.add(rowView);
}
```

Отображение ProgressBar в строке ListView:

```
mUsersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {
        final ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.adapter_row_deleting_progressbar);
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        RestClient.getInstance().addUser(selectedUser.id, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mUsersListAdapter.setEnabled(position, true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
                pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                view.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.move_to_left_animation));
                new Handler() {{
                    postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mUsersListAdapter.removeItem(position);
                            activity.resetFragmentsData();
                        }
                    }, 500);
                }};
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Исходный код layout-файла listadapter_row_item:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_weight=".2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/userlist_photo_height"
    android:id="@+id/listadapterImage"
    android:src="@drawable/empty_user_photo" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight=".6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Lastname"
        android:id="@+id/listadapterMainTextview" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Firstname Middlename"
        android:id="@+id/usersListadapterAdditionalTextview" />

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight=".2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/duty_userlist_photo_height"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/adapter_row_deleting_progressbar"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Вы ж, вроде, и не пытаетесь его заставить вращаться...

Comment: А если без `android:visibility="gone"` для прогресбара, то он вращается?

Comment: вы как-то неправильно используете ListView. Зачем вы храните свои View в списке mViews?